# trying to rebuild the itoa function

Tags: c

my program on only outputs none zero numbers ...eg input = 16076, output = 1676 ... can anyone please help with the maths

```
#include <stdio.h>

char        *ft_itoa(int n)
{

    int count;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int temp;
    int allocated = 0;
    char *val;
    int zero;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        count = n;
        i = 0;
        temp = 1;

        while (count > 0)
        {
            i++;
            count /= 10;
            printf("works %d\n", i);
        }
        if (allocated == 0)
        {
            printf("alocated\n");
            allocated = 1;
            val = (char *)malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(char));
        }

        while (i > 1)
        {
            temp *= 10;
            i--;
            //printf("temp = %d\n", temp);
        }
        val[j] =  n / (temp) + '0';
        n = n - ((temp) * (n / temp));
        //val++;
```

Comment: C++ and C are different languages. Why tag both?

Comment: Actually `itoa()` is not standard in C or C++.   However, when it is supported, it  does not allocate memory.   The string to be written is passed as an argument and the the caller must ensure the array passed is large enough.   As a first cut, try doing the same.

Comment: You have several problems in your code, I explain them and also put a way to do, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code, independently of the fact you do not mimic the usual *atoi* (which get the string in argument, more the basis, and also works on negative numbers)

- you do not change the value of *j* so you only modify `val[0]`, and because the end of the loop is not visible we do not know if you put the final null character *somewhere*
- your code is very complicated for nothing, for instance why do you compute the number of digit and the power of ten each turn ?
- visibly you do not know the modulo operator '%' exists
- *zero* is useless

> my program on only outputs none zero numbers

this is because of your way to count the number of digits each turn, after you removed the two higher digits from 16076 you get 076 so in fact 76 and you bypass the 0

The right way after you computed *one time* the number of digits is to write the number in the reverse order, starting by the lower digit

For instance if like you I allocate the string and only manages positive numbers a solution can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage: %s <positive number>\n", *argv);
  else {
    int n;

    if ((sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n) != 1)  || (n < 0))
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid number '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    else {
      int v;
      size_t ndigits;

      if (n == 0)
        ndigits = 1;
      else 
        for (v = n, ndigits = 0; v != 0; v /= 10, ++ndigits)
          ; /* empty body */

      char * s = malloc(ndigits + 1);

      s[ndigits] = 0;

      do {
        s[--ndigits] = n % 10 + '0';
        n /= 10;
      } while (ndigits != 0);

      puts(s);
      free(s);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall i.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 16076
16076
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out 16076
==6822== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6822== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6822== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6822== Command: ./a.out 16076
==6822== 
16076
==6822== 
==6822== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6822==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6822==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,030 bytes allocated
==6822== 
==6822== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6822== 
==6822== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6822== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: There is no "standard atoi".   It is a non-standard function supported by SOME implementations.

Comment: @Peter you mean _itoa_ ;-) I used 'standard' is the non normative sense of the word, when we speak about _itoa_ every body understand what it is, and it present in all the compilers I know. I edited my answer to replace _standard_ by _usual_ which is more clear ;-)